# Updating cells in table using jEditable, jQuery and DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am very new to using DataTables as well as jQuery.

I am trying to display a table and let the user edit the cells and update the values in the MySQL database.

I don't really understand what the sValue is used for/represents either.

This is my code so far, keeping in mind that I have linked the jeditable.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#parentEditTable').dataTable({
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "ParentId"
            }, {
                "data": "Name"
            }],
        "order": [[0, 'asc']],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "responsive": true,

        "ajax": {
            url: 'processEditParent.php',
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });

    oTable.$('#parentEditTable').editable('processEditParent.php', {

        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.GetPosition( this );
            oTable.upload( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('ParentId'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition(this )[2]
            };

        },
        "height": "14px",
        "width": "100%"
    } );
} );
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work using examples from http://kingkode.com/free-datatables-editor-alternative/ and some of my own code, feel free to comment or ask any questions if you need any help.

Instead of creating a dataSet with static variables, I did a DB query and returned the results as an array and set that array as the dataSet in the dataTable function.